# BaseAdapter Class used with Json Parsing

Tags: android, json, parsing

I have Parsed the Json Response and Now I want to use the BaseAdapter Class in my Application. I have a rough Idea about the BaseAdapter Class but not very clear about the same.

Can anybody please tell me what exactly the Base Class does.

Also do I need to use the Getter and Setter Methods if I am using the BaseAdapter Class in my Application?

Thanks,
david

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BaseAdapter` is a skeleton implementation of `ListAdapter`, reducing the total number of methods you need to implement to create a fully-functioning `ListAdapter`. [Here is a project](http://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-sacklist) that implements `SackOfViewsAdapter`, a `BaseAdapter` that simply holds onto and returns a collection of `Views`.

> Also do I need to use the Getter and Setter Methods if I am using the BaseAdapter Class in my Application?

I do not understand your question, sorry.